# Problem Using Single Security Token for Multiple MQTT Client

Tags: mqtt, node-red, thingsboard, thingsboard-gateway

Below are my setups:

1. ThingsBoard (Community Edition)

- Self-hosted on DigitalOcean

2. Raspberry Pi 4 running the applications below:

- Node-Red collecting data from sensor (DHT22) and publishing it to ThingsBoard using "MQTT Out" node
- [ThingsBoard IoT Gateway](https://thingsboard.io/docs/iot-gateway/) (TIG) connecting to ThingsBoard using "MQTT Connector"

I'm able to publish all the sensor data from Node-Red to ThingsBoard using MQTT. The problem is that I need to use ThingsBoard "RPC Remote Shell" function. In order to achieve this I've installed TIG on my Raspberry Pi.

Both Node-Red and TIG are using the same "Security Token". When TIG is connected to ThingsBoard it will interrupt Node-Red's connection to ThingsBoard.

For now, as a workaround, I had to create two "Device" within ThingsBoard in order to get two different "Security Token". One token is for Node-Red and another is for TIG. This seems to sort out the problem temporarily but I ended up with two logical "Device" within ThingsBoard for one physical device (Raspberry Pi).

Is there a setting that to allow multiple connection from one "Security Token" on ThingsBoard? Or which part of ThingsBoard's codes do I need to edit in order to allow it? Or perhaps there's a way to enable "RPC Remote Shell" including other RPC capabilities using Node-Red instead of TIG? I have to use Node-Red as this is the easiest method to gather data instead of TIG. Let me know if you have a creative solution for this problem.

Appreciate your help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This behaviour is controlled by ACTORS_MAX_CONCURRENT_SESSION_PER_DEVICE configuration parameter. The default value is 1. You may change this value to 2. Then both sessions will work. Although it is not recommended to change the value if you subscribe to RPC or attribute updates in both device applications (MQTT sessions).